# How to jump to next breakpoint in Pydev Python debugging

Tags: python, linux, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I am using `Eclipse` along with `Pydev` for python programming. I have a remote device which runs on linux and my development machine also runs on linux. I need to test and debug the python scripts on remote machine.

For this, I make a ssh connection to the remote machine and then open the python file. There I add below lines:

```
import sys;
import pydevd;pydevd.settrace("192.168.1.155",port=5678)
```

So when I run the python file it stops after the above lines from where I start my debugging. If I put a breakpoint somewhere else in the code, then how can I make it to jump to that breakpoint and start from there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`settrace` actually has a `suspend` parameter to which you can pass `False` if you don't want to stop at that line... (sorry, haven't added to the docs, but you may see it at: https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/master/pydevd.py#L1121)

So, you could do: `import pydevd;pydevd.settrace("192.168.1.155",port=5678, suspend=False)` that way it'll not stop at that line, only in the first breakpoint you set in the IDE.

After hitting any breakpoint, <kbd>F8</kbd> can be used to continue running until another breakpoint is hit (note that you need to be in the debug perspective for <kbd>F8</kbd> to work -- otherwise, you have to customize your perspective so that the debugger actions are active in a different perspective).

p.s.: <kbd>F7</kbd> is step return, <kbd>F6</kbd> step next and <kbd>F5</kbd> step into.